# Multiplication in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

My problem is I do not know if the entity adder is right or wrong.
My other question is where I have to put the entity adder, in the same module that the entity mult? Or should I create another module?

heres is my code: Is a multiplication code of two 5bits number in
VHDL.
    I don´t know here is the problem: library, site of the declaration of signals or variables, ..?

```
`library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL; 
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity mult is
   port (op1    : in  std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);--a
     op2    : in  std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);--x
     out : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)); --pp
end mult;

architecture Behavioral of mult is
type t_matrix is array (0 to 5, 10 downto 0) of std_logic;
signal c, sum, mul : t_matrix ;
signal sum_ini : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) ;



begin
   rows  :  for i in 0 to 3 generate
       columns  : for j in 0 to 9 generate
           i_u : adder port map(a => sum_ini(j),
                              b =>c(i,j),
                              cin => mul(i, j),
                              sum => sum(i+1, j),
                              cout => c(i+1, j+1));
        end generate columns;
    end generate rows;

   p_multiplications : process (a, b)
   --variable v_producto : t_pp := ((others => (others => ’0’)));
   begin -- process multiplications
   for i in 0 to 4 loop
      for j in 0 to 4 loop
          if i = 0 then
            sum_ini(j) <= a(0) and b(j);
         else
            mul(i-1, j+i) <= a(i) and b(j);
         end if;
      end loop; -- j
   end loop; -- i
   end process p_multiplications;

end Behavioral;´
```

> ---
>
> ```
> --I have another module my entity adder , but I don´t know where is the problem.
> ```

```
`entity adder is
port (  a   : in  std_logic_vector (9 downto 0));
end adder; 

architecture Behavioral of adder is 
type t_matrix is array (0 to 5, 10 downto 0) of std_logic;
signal cout, b, cin, sum  :   t_matrix  ;
begin 
sum <= (a xor cin) xor b; 
cout <= (a and b)or(cin and a)or(cin and b); 
end Behavioral;´
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: You have the reserved word out used as a signal name in the entity declaration mult.  You don't show where the operators for type t_matrix in adder are defined (xor, and).

Comment: my problem is I do not know if the entity adder is right or wrong.
My other question is where I have to put the entity adder,  in the same module that the entity mult? or I should create another module. Sorry about my English !!

Comment: I change out for result, but it isn´t the problem.

Comment: How I can  defined operators (xor, and)?

Comment: @user2985159 xor and and are in std_logic_1164 package

Comment: "but it isn´t the problem". Ok but what is?

Comment: Notice a is a single dimension array (9 downto 0) type std_logic_vector, cout, b, cin and sum are arrays of  dimension 6 x 11 of std_logic. How do you expect to xor or and or, or those together? It doesn't look like from usage you should be declaring anything t_matrix in adder. Also the left and right side of an operator (e.g. xor) should have the same range. VHDL doesn't have the concept of modules, the applicable equivalent is 'design unit'.  Design units are contained in design files, any number of design units can be in one design file.

Comment: And if you have more than one design unit in a design file there can be an analysis order dependency (which says adder should come first).

Comment: Then test the adder! Write a testbench, feed test data into it, compare the adder outputs with the data you expect,

Comment: Having this on hold is not helpful for those of us that can see numerous issues and provide some useful feedback.  So I will answer with several comments.

Comment: Issue 1:  Put each entity and architecture pair in a separate file.  Each entity needs its own context declarations - the library and use clauses.  Entities are linked through the library provided you follow the correct compile order.  A simplified view of the correct compile order is compile your design hierarchy bottom up - subblocks before the design that references it.  Note though in general any depth first search compile order is fine.  So if you look at David Koontz's post, the order he put the entities in is important.

Comment: Issue 2:  Use only NUMERIC_STD.  You have referenced two different conflicting math packages:  NUMERIC_STD and STD_LOGIC_ARITH.  I recommend NUMERIC_STD as it is an IEEE standard.  While STD_LOGIC_ARITH is in the IEEE library, it is shareware produced by one of the EDA vendors.  If you tried to use the type unsigned or signed in your code, it would not work due to it being defined in both packages.  You can reference it by IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.unsigned, but you don't need to do this if you only reference NUMERIC_STD.  Fortunately in the code you shared you are not using these types.

Comment: Issue 3:  Do math with math operators(ie: + - *).  This is obviously a college problem.  It emphasizes the architecture of arithmetic operations.  The issue is that most synthesis tools do not see this code as half adders and full adders, but just as random logic.  In an FPGA, this can mean that carry chains get implemented on normal logic outputs rather than carry chain outputs.  This is important as FPGA carry chain outputs are around 10X faster than normal outputs.  To the college professors reading this, please rethink your problems to take advantage of the strengths of synthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get "xor", and "and" operators, put these lines at the top of your module

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
```

The other problem is that you can't get a 10 bit adder by taking the logic for a single bit adder and simply make the signals wider. You need to organize things so that the cin for bit 1 is the cout of bit 0, etc.

```
cin(9 downto 1) <= cout(8 downto 0);
```

You need to add b, carry_in, carry_out to the port declarations for entity adder.

Comment: Thanks David , thanks B..